# boost::thread interrupt() throws an exception only the first time that an interruption point is executed?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, interruptions

boost::thread interrupt() throws an exception only the first time that an interruption point is executed? My case is the following.

I create a `boost::thread` which executes `functionA.` `functionA` calls `functionB` and when on `functionB` we call function `threadInterrupt.` `functionB` throws a `boost::thread_interrupted` exception and returns to `functionA.` My question is if a new `boost::thread_interrupted` exception will be throw in functionA when another interruption point is executed.

```
void MyClass::function(int arg1, int arg2) try {
    boost::thread* t = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::functionA, this, var1, var2));
} catch (...) {
    cout << "function throw an exception" << endl;
}

void MyClass::functionA(int arg1, int arg2 ) try {
    //some code here
    try {
        int retVal = MyClass::functionB(var);
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        //some code here
    } catch(boost::thread_interrupted&) {
        cout << "thread interrupted in functionA" << endl;
    }
} catch (...) {
    cout << "functionA throw an exception" << endl;
}

int MyClass::functionB(int arg1) try {
    //some code here
    try {
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        //some code here
    } catch(boost::thread_interrupted&) {
        cout << "thread interrupted in functionB" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
} catch (...) {
    cout << "functionB throw an exception" << endl;
    return 1;
}

void MyClass::threadInterrupt() {
    if (thr!=NULL) {
        thr->interrupt();
        thr->join();
        delete thr;
        thr=NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it? See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48485eecd100e506)**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
    thread t([]{
            int i = 0;
            while (true) try {
                if (i >= 10) return;
                while (i < 10) {
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
                    std::cout << "processed " << i++ << "\n";
                }
            }
            catch (...) { std::cout << "Interrupted at i = " << i << "\n"; }
    });

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
    t.interrupt();

    t.join();
    std::cout << "Interrupt requested? : " << std::boolalpha << t.interruption_requested() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
processed 0
processed 1
processed 2
Interrupted at i = 3
processed 3
processed 4
processed 5
processed 6
processed 7
processed 8
processed 9
Interrupt requested? : false
```

As you can see the interrupt request behaves like a sort of auto-reset flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified my code and added in functionB `std::cout << "Interrupt requested in functionB? : " << std::bool alpha << boost::this_thread::interruption_requested() << "\n" << endl;` and in functionA `std::cout << "Interrupt requested in functionB? : " << std::bool alpha << boost::this_thread::interruption_requested() << "\n" << endl;` and the output I got was `Interrupt requested in functionB? :true Interrupt requested in functionA? :false`

Comment: @KoKa there you go :) Answering your own question: once the `thread_interrupted` exception has been thrown, the "flag" is canceled.

Comment: My case is that if functionB is interrupted, functionA should be interrupted too, I don't want code of functionA to be executed. Is there any way so that interruption_point of functionA is executed as well?

Comment: @KoKa you could interrupt the running thread (have a reference to it somehwere). You could throw the `interrupted_exception` yourself (I recommend using a custom type to avoid confusion); Or why don't you use the return value to know that the task needs to be canceled?

Comment: I am interrupting the running thread, or at least I think that I am doing so! When I create the new thread (void MyClass::function) I keep a reference to it (boost::thread* t) which I interrupt and joing in function void MyClass::threadInterrupt(). Am I doing something wrong? Could you please explain me how I can use the interrupted_exception thrown by myself in order to interrupt code execution of both functions?

Comment: @KoKa I assume the thread running while calling `thr->interrupt();` is **not** the thread referenced by the thread object named `*thr`. Otherwise, obviously just `throw thread_interrupted()` or even just `return 0` would seem easier. I don't really know what about `throw thread_interrupted()` I can explain more than I already did. You know, throwing that _from_ `functionB` simply **[makes that function an "interruption point", just like any other?](http://tinyurl.com/pp6d5jt)**. `functionA` wouldn't (need to) know what interruption point raised the exception.